# Deleting a folder in a directory with the same name, but its in different places inside the directory

Tags: powershell, delete-directory

So, I have a folder that is repeated in a directory in many different folders and I want to avoid having to code every single folder location. I just want to delete all of them from all places in 1 line, if that's possible. Here's what I have so far:

```
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\dwilson\Desktop\HTFS_v3.9_201511193\Databases" -Filter *onetimescripts* -force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
```

The error it returns is:

> ```
>  Remove-Item : Cannot remove item 
>     C:\Users\dwilson\Desktop\HTFS_v3.9_201511193\Databases\HTFSJob\BAM\onetimescripts: 
>      The directory is not empty.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Remove-Item -Path "C:\Users\dwilson\Desktop\HTFS_v3.9_201511193\Databases" -Filt 
> ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (onetimescripts:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-It 
>    em], IOException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
>    ands.RemoveItemCommand
> ```

I feel like this is probably a very simple fix, but I'm not able to find it.

Comment: Try doing a `Get-ChildItem` instead of a `Remove-Item` and check your results.  If it finds exactly the stuff you're trying to delete, run the command again and pipe it to `Remove-Item -Force` and let me know what you get.

Comment: i did try that after i posted the question and the get-childitem definitely finds the folders i want to delete but then it tells me "the path does not exist" here is what i put: `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\dwilson\Desktop\HTFS_v3.9_201511193\Databases\" -Name "onetimescripts" -Directory -Recurse | Remove-Item`  and they definitely do exist.

Comment: i got it! i added the `force` and `recurse` at the end of the `remove-item` command and it worked! i tried that before and it didnt work... not sure why thanks for your help!

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and select it as the correct answer so this question falls off the list, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path" -Name "foldername" -Directory -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: wont let me do it for 2 days

Comment: Yep, I forgot.  Thanks!